# in flutter when I pass model class in one of the Tab screen I get error in main Bottom Navigation screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

What I need to pass in BottomNav where I have mentioned all my tabs?

This is More TAB where I want to pass my MODEL class in widget:-

```
class More extends StatefulWidget{
final UserData currentUser; //UserData is model class
More(this.currentUser,) ;

@override
_MoreState createState() => new _MoreState();

 }
```

And this is BottomNav screen, where I have mentioned all my TAB (I have commented line next to More()where I get error):-

```
  class _BottomNavState  extends State<BottomNav> {


 int _index = 0;
 List<Widget> _items = [
 Home(),
  UserProfile(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,imageList: [],currentIndex:0),
  Notifications(),
  Chat(),
  More(), /// I get error(red line below More() that I need to pass something here. What is that? So, that I can call my model class in widget.
 ];


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error that you have?

Comment: lib/BottomNavigation/bottomNav.dart:29:9: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
    More(),
        ^
lib/BottomNavigation/more.dart:17:2: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
 More(this.currentUser,) ;

Comment: what content? I am not getting. Are you saying BottomNave screen full code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an `UserData` to your `More` stateful widget since you declared that the `More` widget is expecting a `UserData` as a parameter

Such as:

```dart
final myUserData = UserData();
//...
More(myUserData),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your constructor like this

```
More(this.currentUser);
```

Which makes the `currentUser` as a mandatory `positional parameter` at position 0.

So while using your class, you should compulsorily pass an object of `UserData` like this,

```
More(UserData());
```

But in case, it is not mandatory, then you need to change your constructor to this,

```
More({ this.currentUser });
```

Comment: yes that error gone but now Igetting this:- type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'UserData' of 'function result'

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you have a function named `result` whose return type is `UserData`, but inside the function, you are actually return an instance of `User` class.

Comment: not getting, where it is . neither error taking me to the link.

Comment: can you come on any desk? for 2 mins, if it is OK with u

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com/ and paste your full code and share link

Comment: Sure, I can  come

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232704/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-nisanth-reddy).